# How do I code for both Lync 2010 and Skype For Business

Tags: c#, skype-for-business, lync-2010

I need to write an application that handles incoming and outgoing calls from both Lync 2010 and Skype For Business.

From my understanding of the Lync SDKs.

- Lync 2013 SDK works with Skype For Business; however, it will not
  work with Lync 2010.
- Lync 2010 SDK also doesn't seem to work with Lync 2013.

My question is: Is there a way in which I can code for both Lync 2010 and SFB so that they can share the same code or do I have to code them both separately?

**Additional Information**

We use both SFB and Lync 2010. These calls include Calls from other Lync/Skype users as well as PSTN calls [Calls internal and external via skype/lync or telephone (PBX)].

We're currently in a transition from Lync 2010 to SfB (This will take a really long time). The current application will not work for SfB, so I have to add that in. Unfortunately, the original code is written using UCCAPI. I planned to rewrite this code with Lync SDK since the code will be simpler, safer, and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

At first, it depends on the calls, are they PSTN calls or calls from other Lync/SfB users on the same environment? Because if the users are on the same SfB environment then a so called peer2peer call might occour and this will not involve the server.

The 2nd point is [Lync 2010 reached the mainstream support since April 2016](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/skypeforbusiness/312-end-of-mainstream-support-for-lync-2010.html) so most companies should considering now an upgrade to a newer version as Lync 2010 will be soon end of life. I personally wouldn´t build something for an Software which is that old.

Based on that I think you might mean Lync 2013 & Skype for Business. So without knowing what you wish to build as you didn´t go into details:

- In general Lync Server 2013 CU1 and above used UCWA 1.0.* (Lync 2013 RTM didn´t have UCWA) while Skype for business Server 2015 used UCWA 2.0.*
- In coexistence mode (Lync 2010 and Skype for Business 2015) you must point the Autodiscover CNAME (Lyncdiscover. and LyncDiscoverinternal.) to a Skype for Business Server 2015 pool in order support custom UCWA 2.0 application development (as written [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-docs/blob/master/Skype/UCWA/RootURL.md)). But that's for Lync 2010 which do not have any UCWA on its frontend server as written [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/270f79b2-12e2-488f-951e-82ead67fcd0e/ucwa-on-lync-2010?forum=ucwebapi).
- A Lync 2013 mobile client used also the UCWA (as mentioned [here](http://www.msxfaq.de/lync/mobile/lync2013mobileios.htm) or [here](http://blog.schertz.name/2013/07/understanding-lync-2013-mobility/)) and is compatible with Skype for Business.
- The UCWA 1.0 Code samples, Get started, What is this API?, Core features and Reference URLs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj162980.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) all points now to the UCWA 2.0 links so they are compatible (in some ways)

So I would try to build something with UCWA is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added more information in the question and hope that clarifies the situation a bit more. I will try to read over the documents for UCWA and try to build something with it.